# npm install not working after updating to v6.9

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

`npm` giving error MODULE_NOT_FOUND.

What could be wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `npm` folder from `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\` and then **reinstall** using the nodejs installer.

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3540)

**Note:** I recommend you to use a node version manager such as [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).